# Why is a specific method call in my VBA program leaving an instance of Excel running in the background after the program is done?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have VBA code in Access that processes some queries. A recordset is created from each query and then exported to Excel. After exporting, a FormatWorksheets sub is called to give some formatting to the excel file. Then, the recordset might also be exported to a specified worksheet in a generalized results file (created from an Excel template file). Again, once exported, FormatWorksheets is called for that specific sheet in the generalized results file.

I noticed that an instance of Excel was hanging around in the background processes section of my task manager after running my program. After some process of elimination I realized that if I comment out the call to FormatWorksheets that specifically formats the general results file, this doesn't happen (the specific line is highlighted below). Can anyone tell me why? Also, when I leave that line uncommented, one of the statements in my FormatWorksheets method will sometimes generate runtime error 462, but not always. If anyone knows what's causing that I'd love to hear it.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub ExportData()

    'object variables
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim oFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    'variables for creating results files and folders
    Dim strRootPath As String
    Dim strFilepath As String
    Dim strFilePathIncorrect As String
    Dim strDirectory As String
    Dim strFilename As String
    Dim strFullFilepath As String
    Dim strSummaryFilename As String
    Dim strTemplateName As String
    Dim strWorksheetName As String
    Dim strQueryName As String
    Dim strDate As String
    Dim intYear As Integer
    Dim strMonth As String
    Dim intDay As Integer
    Dim intCount As Integer
    'boolean flags
    Dim blnEXCEL As Boolean
    Dim blnExportToResultsSummary As Boolean

    blnEXCEL = False
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    intCount = 0
    strDate = Format(Date, "mmddyy")
    intYear = Year(Date)
    strMonth = MonthName(Month(Date))
    intDay = Day(Date)

    strRootPath = "C:\Desktop\Practice Runs\"

    'create folders for Excel files
    strFilepath = strRootPath & "Results\"
    If Dir(strFilepath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir strFilepath
    End If
    strFilepath = strRootPath & "Results\" & strMonth & " " & intDay & "\"
    If Dir(strFilepath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir strFilepath
    End If
    strFilePathIncorrect = strFilepath & "Incorrect References\"
    If Dir(strFilePathIncorrect, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir strFilePathIncorrect
    End If

    'get Excel object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        blnEXCEL = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    objExcel.Visible = False

    'create summary file from template
    strTemplateName = "C:\Desktop\Practice Runs\Templates\Summary template.xlsm"
    strSummaryFilename = strFilepath & "Results Summary - " & strMonth & " " & intDay & " " & intYear & ".xlsm"
    oFSO.copyfile strTemplateName, strSummaryFilename, True
    Set xlWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strSummaryFilename)

    'process query and export results to excel files
    strDirectory = strFilePathIncorrect
    strQueryName = "Query1"
    strFilename = strDate & " Incorrect Results.xlsx"
    strFullFilepath = strDirectory & strFilename
    strWorksheetName = "Incorrect"
    intCount = ProcessQuery(rs, strQueryName, strFullFilepath, strWorksheetName, xlWorkbook, blnExportToResultsSummary:=True)

    '...some more processing of intCount...

    '...process more queries...

    'clean up
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    xlWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Set xlWorkbook = Nothing
    If blnEXCEL = True Then
        objExcel.Quit
    End If
    Set objExcel = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing

    MsgBox "Check Completed"

End Sub

Function ProcessQuery(rs As Object, strQueryName As String, strFullFilepath As String, strWorksheetName As String, xlWorkbook As Object, blnExportToResultsSummary As Boolean)

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * from [" & strQueryName & "]")

    If rs.EOF = False Then
        rs.MoveLast
        ProcessQuery = rs.recordCount
        ExportToExcel rs, strFullFilepath, "", Nothing        'export query results to Excel file in the specified folder

        If blnExportToResultsSummary = True Then              'export query results to specified sheet in results summary file
            ExportToExcel rs, , strWorksheetName, xlWorkbook
        End If
    Else
        ProcessQuery = rs.recordCount  'no records found
    End If

End Function

Sub ExportToExcel(rs As Object, Optional ByVal strFilepath As String = "", Optional ByVal strWorksheetName As String = "", Optional ByVal xlSummaryFile As Object = Nothing)

    Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorksheet As Excel.worksheet
    Dim xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim rngCurrentCell As Excel.Range
    Dim lngColumn As Long

    If strWorksheetName = "" Then 'export recordset to Excel file in the appropriate folder

        On Error Resume Next
        Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
        If objExcel = "" Then
            Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        End If
        objExcel.ScreenUpdating = False
        objExcel.Visible = False

        'if file already exists, delete it
        If Dir(strFilepath) <> "" Then
            Kill strFilepath
        End If
        Set xlWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
        xlWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=strFilepath

        Set xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Set rngCurrentCell = xlWorksheet.Range("A1")

        'write headers to worksheet
        For lngColumn = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            rngCurrentCell.Offset(0, lngColumn).Value = rs.Fields(lngColumn).Name
        Next lngColumn
        Set rngCurrentCell = rngCurrentCell.Offset(1, 0)

        ' write data to worksheet
        rs.MoveFirst
        rngCurrentCell.CopyFromRecordset rs

        FormatWorksheets xlWorksheet, blnNotesColumn:=False       'THIS CALL DOESN'T CAUSE BACKGROUND PROCESS TO HANG AROUND

        objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
        xlWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
        objExcel.DisplayAlerts = True

    Else 'export recordset to specified sheet in summary file

        Set xlWorksheet = xlSummaryFile.Worksheets(strWorksheetName)
        xlWorksheet.Cells.Clear
        Set rngCurrentCell = xlWorksheet.Range("A1")

        'write headers to worksheet
        For lngColumn = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            rngCurrentCell.Offset(0, lngColumn).Value = rs.Fields(lngColumn).Name
        Next lngColumn
        Set rngCurrentCell = rngCurrentCell.Offset(1, 0)

        ' write data to worksheet
        rs.MoveFirst
        rngCurrentCell.CopyFromRecordset rs

        FormatWorksheets xlWorksheet, blnNotesColumn:=True       'CALLING THIS CAUSES BACKGROUND PROCESS TO HANG AROUND

        xlSummaryFile.Save

    End If

    rs.MoveFirst
    Set rngCurrentCell = Nothing
    Set xlWorksheet = Nothing
    Set xlWorkbook = Nothing
    Set objExcel = Nothing

End Sub

Sub FormatWorksheets(xlWorksheet As Object, blnNotesColumn As Boolean)

    With xlWorksheet
        .Activate
        .Range("A1").Select
        Selection.End(xlToRight).Select                        'sometimes causes run-time error 462
        .Range("A1:" & ActiveCell.Address).Font.Bold = True
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

        If blnNotesColumn = True Then
            'Add notes column
            .Range("A1").Select
            Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Notes"
            ActiveCell.ColumnWidth = 60
            ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
        End If

        'Add borders to entire used area
        .UsedRange.Select
        Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
        Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        Range("A1").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With

        'Format date column
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Activate
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
        Range("A1").Select
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Fully qualify Excel references. Not just `Range` but `Worksheeets("name").Range` or `.Range`. See end of formatting procedure. There are 5 lines using `Range` to fix. Also, 'Activeanything` can be an issue. It is usually not necessary to select a cell or range to act on it.

Comment: I temporarily created a second FormatWorksheets2 method to handle just the results summary file. I added the xlWorkbook and strSheetName as an arguments and put this statement in the beginning: `Set xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheeName)` I also made your other suggested changes. This still results in excel in the background after everything is done. Thoughts?

Comment: In `ExportToExcel` you potentially create an Excel instance but don't Quit it.  Also that `On Error Resume Next` should be cancelled as soon as you no longer need it.

Comment: @TimWilliams I guess I don't need the `CreateObject` If-statement in `ExportToExcel` because the results summary file is always going to be open before `ExportToExcel` is called, so GetObject will bind to that. I just took it out (as well as `On Error Resume Next`) and my problem still persists

Comment: Try making Excel visible in case there's some alert/popup you're missing when it tries to close. Maybe also look into removing your use of Select/Activate in `FormatWorksheets` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: Please install the free and fantastic Rubberduck add in for VBA.  The code inspections will help a lot when trying to understand about qualifying references.

Answer (score 1):

I took the suggestion made by Tim Williams and June7 and changed my `FormatWorksheets` code to eliminate any Select/Activate usage, and it worked. I no longer have any excel instances hanging around after the program is done running. Here is the altered code:

```
Sub FormatWorksheets(xlWorksheet As Object, blnNotesColumn As Boolean)
    
    Dim currentRng As Excel.Range
    
    With xlWorksheet
        Set currentRng = .Range("A1").End(xlToRight)
        .Range("A1:" & currentRng.Address).Font.Bold = True
        Set currentRng = .Range("A1:" & currentRng.Address)
        currentRng.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
        If blnNotesColumn = True Then
            'Add notes column
            Set currentRng = .Range("A1")
            Set currentRng = currentRng.End(xlToRight)
            Set currentRng = currentRng.Offset(0, 1)
            currentRng.FormulaR1C1 = "Notes"
            currentRng.ColumnWidth = 60
            currentRng.Font.Bold = True
        End If
    
        'Add borders to entire used area
        Set currentRng = .UsedRange
        currentRng.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
        currentRng.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
        With currentRng.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With currentRng.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With currentRng.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With currentRng.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With currentRng.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With currentRng.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        Set currentRng = .Range("A1:" & currentRng.End(xlToRight).Address)
        With currentRng.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    
        'Format date column
        Set currentRng = .Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, -2)
        Set currentRng = .Range(currentRng.Address & ":" & currentRng.End(xlDown).Address)
        currentRng.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
        Set currentRng = .Range("A1")
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```